# PDF preview with visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, pdf, html

I need to open a pdf preview of my offer generated by a custom button on opportunity page.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Currently this works as normal html page, but my problem is that I am not able to manage page interruptions.

[image]

In preview mode you can edit some fields

[image]

HTML code:

```
                page[size="A4"] {  
                  width: 21cm;
                  height: 29.7cm;
                }

                page {
                  font-family: "Arial";
                  font-size: 12pt;
                  letter-spacing: 1px;
                  background: white;
                  display: block;
                  margin: auto;
                  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
                  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
                  text-align:justify;
                  line-height: 150%;
                }
    <page size="A4">
    Page 1 ...some text here...
    </page>

    <page size="A4">
    Page 2...some text here...
    </page>
```

How to divide the text into separate pages?
Any way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I've used the below styling to manage page breaks in the past when generating a PDF from a VF page. This will create a page break after the div.

```
<div style="page-break-after:always;" />
```

Check out below link for other properties you could use:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp

Comment: Yes, I know this tag and I've used to print my pdf.
My issue here is that in this preview the text is contained in each <page> tag

Comment: Why are you using a page tag? Could you provide more code? I'm not able to recreate this.